# Why my form not sowing any validation errors after i click the submit button in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I've two forms rendering in a single function based view, it is diplaying validation errors of only one form when i click the signup button but when i click the login button it just reload my page
and doesn't showing any validation error

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    form = RegisterForm()
    form_b = LogInForm()
    if request.POST.get('submit') == 'sign_up':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    elif request.POST.get('submit') == 'log_in':
        form1 = LogInForm(request=request, data=request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid():
            uname = form1.cleaned_data['username']
            upass = form1.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=uname, password=upass)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/shop/')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
        form_b = LogInForm()
    return render(request, 'reg.html', {'form': form, 'form1': form_b})
```

**forms.py**

```
from distutils.command.clean import clean
from xml.dom import ValidationErr
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']

class LogInForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

**reg.html**

```
<form class="loginForm" action="" method="POST" novalidate>        
        {% csrf_token %} 
        {% for field in form %}
           <p> {{field.label_tag}}  {{field}} </p>
           <p> {{field.errors}} </p>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" class="btnLogin" name='submit' value='sign_up'>Sign Up</button>
     </form>
     <form class="loginForm" action="" method="post" novalidate> 
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form1 %}
           <p> {{field.label_tag}}  {{field}} </p>
           <p> {{field.errors | striptags}} </p>
        {% endfor %}
     <button  class="btnLogin" type="submit"  name='submit' value='log_in'>Log In </button>
     </form>
```

Comment: why there is `novalidate` in `form` tag

Answer (score 0):

Try to create seperate view for both register and login.

try this way:

**views.py:**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            # messages.success(request,f'Welcome { username }')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/users/')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request,'users/register.html',{'form':form})
```

And in urls.py:

```
path('login',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'),name='login'),
```